# Convert String to Date Object in Java

Tags: java, date

I need to parse the following string into a date object in java:

```
String time = "Jul 24 2012 05:19:34";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = df.parse(time);
```

The code throws this exception:

```
Unparseable date: "Jul 24 2012 05:19:34"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Note: `MMM`

Comment: I have to wait 12 minutes before I can accept your answer. I don't know why.

Comment: @user1467855 So you can review all answers and accept the best.

Answer (score 2):

Format string should be - `"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 2):

'MMM' use for getting month name in alphabet of first three letter
'MM' use for getting month number of the year

String time = "Jul 24 2012 05:19:34";

Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");//MMM return Jul

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");    // MM return 07

Answer (score 1):

The Date.parse method is deprecated, but will still work just fine:

```
    Date d = new Date(Date.parse(time));
    System.out.println(d);
```

However, if you wish to continue your method, add one more M to the MM part of your format (now MMM)

Comment: Why would he switch to a deprecated method?  The one he's using is perfect for the job, he just has to change one character in his format string.

Answer (score 1):

The format should be - "MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss" not "MM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss".
You can refer to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) . Mark the difference between minute mm and month mmm