# Java Date object constructor for getting string is deprecated

Tags: java, string, date, deprecated

I have problem using Date in java,
I have a string that represent a date for example String date = "23/10/2012";
and i have a function that get a date as parameter, for example

```
public void foo(Date date){...}
```

my problem is that Date constructor that accept a string is deprecated and i do not want to use
a deprecated  object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you look at the [Javadoc for the deprecated method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28java.lang.String%29) which specifies:

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s).

You then look up [`DateFormat.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) and proceed accordingly. You probably want to create a `SimpleDateFormat` - or better still, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which is a much better date/time API.

When a method is deprecated, it's always a good idea to give an indication of what existing code should be migrated to, and ideally why the old method was deprecated. Follow this guidance when you deprecate your own methods... and whenever you try to *use* a deprecated method, check the documentation to see if it suggests a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I probably should have looked better in the JD, also there already a solution for this problem in this site under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624625/convert-string-to-date-object-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Use [**SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) to parse a string to **java.util.Date** object

```
String date = "23/10/2012"  
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use [SimpleDatFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (or) [Joda library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Example:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(yourDateString);
```